# Creating Immersions, android:immersive="true" flag

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

Per the [Creating Immersions](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/immersions#creating_immersions) documentation one can `Specify android:immersive="true" for your <activity> element to give immersions focus after a screen sleeps and wakes up.`

From my experience, this returns you to the last activity that the user was on before Glass went to sleep, for example: If the user went to ActivityA, then ActivityB, then ActivityC, and Glass goes to sleep, when the user wakes Glass up they're returned to ActivityC.

Is there a way to have the user returned to a specific activity? Say, the same scenario happens as described above, but when Glass wakes up the user is returned to ActivityA?

Thanks in advance, Cole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a member boolean variable like mInitialLaunch in Activity B and C.  In onCreate of Activity B and C set mInitialLaunch to true.

At the end of onResume in B and C, set mInitialLaunch to false.

At the start of onResume in B and C, check mInitialLaunch and if it is false (meaning only onResume was called) launch Activity A.

This is a way to game the Activity LifeCycle to do what you want.

If you want more information about the Activity LifeCycle and Glass ...

This is an open source project I created to help students learning Glass and Android basics get up to speed on the Activity LifeCycle:

https://github.com/mscheel/glass-book-activity-lifecycle-explorer

Comment: Mark, that worked for the most part. There is one edge case in the following scenario when initially starting the app normally with "ok glass, <voice trigger", ActivityA loads, ActivityB loads. Glass goes to sleep. Glass wakes up. ActivityB is initially shown then quickly switches to ActivityA (which is acceptable) - here's the edge case - when going from ActivityA to ActivityB again - Glass goes to sleep before ActivityB can be fully launched.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but if my answer worked for you accept it or if it helped up-vote it.  You might need another question for your edge case and should probably share some code in it.